Web development in Spring Framework - missing Debug Toolbar & Profiler
is there any initiative to build something similar to Symfony web debug toolbar & profiler?
I am missing such a thing in Spring Web Development
Example:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4/debug-toolbar-profiler
https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html

